# Wix custom-action dll after files installed at execution

Tags: c#, dll, wix, windows-installer

I'm using a dll to install a driver that's packaged inside the msi.
Following is the snippet:

```
<Binary Id="CustomAction2.CA.dll"
src="../artifacts/CustomAction2.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="Install"                
        Execute="deferred"
        BinaryKey="CustomAction2.CA.dll" 
        DllEntry="CustomAction1" />

<CustomAction Id="InstallWithProperty"
        Property="Install"
        Value="location=[DEFAULT_INSTALLDIR]$FULL_NAME;name=myDll.dll" Execute="immediate"/>        


<InstallExecuteSequence>      
<Custom Action="InstallWithProperty" After="InstallInitialize"/>
<Custom Action="Install" After="InstallFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I am facing same problem. when Custom action is invoked it says.

> Exception thrown by custom action:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException:
>   Unable to load DLL 'myDll.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at
>   CustomAction2.CustomActions.ConfigDriver(IntPtr hwndParent, UInt16
>   fRequest, String lpszDriver, String lpszArgs, String lpszMsg, UInt16
>   cbMsgMax, Int64& pcbMsgOut) at
>   CustomAction2.CustomActions.CustomAction1(Session session) --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
>   Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture) at
>   Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32
>   sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
>   CustomAction Install returned actual error code 1603 (note this may
>   not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

Can somebody help. I want to use myDll.dll for further installation, which is part of .msi file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing mydll.dll which means it'll try to find it in the current directory / temp directory that the DTF CA is running in.  Instead pass it the file key of the file. ( File @ Id attribute ).

name=[#myDLL.dll]    This will get formatted to something like C:\Program Files\My Company\My Product\myDLL.dll

An alternative is to add the DLL to your CA project so that it gets packaged inside the CA and extracted to the CA current directory at install time.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, The DLL is an unmanaged one, so that is why i cannot add it to my CA project

Comment: You can add it as content copy | always.

Comment: how to do that, can you please tell me

Comment: Same as any C# project in Visual Studio.  Right Click the Project, Add | Existing Item | Filter based on *.* and select your DLL and click OK.  Then select your DLL in the Project and in Properties verify Build Action is Content and set Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always. Now when you build your CA the DLL will be included in .CA.DLL and extracted to current directory and available during your CA execution life cycle.